# A better way of retrieving interval data for AWS lambda function other than DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda function running every 10 seconds(24/7), basically the only thing it does is writing a value (Z) to TimestreamDB. This value (Z) is the result of the multiplication X*Y. X is the sensor's reading value and Y is a multiplier fetched from DynamoDB.

This thing may work, but i don't want to read dynamoDB table every 10 seconds just for a value that is going to change mostly 2-3 times per year. I would like to know if there is a way (cheaper and faster) to save this (Y) value and access it every time from the Lambda function,instead of reading it from dynamoDB as i mentioned.

Take notice, that this app will serve different users, so the X and Y value will be different for every user. Meaning that i can't for example "hard-code" the (Y) value to the function an change it manually every 6 months.

Comment: if the value does not change (often) you can just put a basic cache into your lambda function that only talks to dynamodb once or only every 1 hour to retrieve the value and otherwise returns the previously retrieved value.

Comment: Will this still work with multiple users running the function (each one with different base value)?

Comment: You can build a cache with the user as the key / identifier.

Comment: What runtime is used by your Lambda? Perhaps we could provide sample code for a local key-value cache with configurable TTL

Comment: Changed my architecture guys! It's much better now, i had sensors sending values and i needed to multiply the incoming data by an index value. Now i make the sensors do the calculation based on the index. When the index value changes, they will receive it by subscribing to the "update topic" published by the index update Lambda function